# How to create an additional boolean column in a view whose value depends on a subquery?

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, optimization, query-performance

Following is a view that I have created

```
CREATE VIEW [ForMasterTable] 
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT
[MasterID],
[MasterColumnData],
[DetailID],
[DetailColumnData],
[SomeOtherID],
[SomeOtherColumnData]

FROM [MasterTable]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [DetailTable] ON [MasterTable].[DetailID]= [DetailTable].[DetailID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [SomeOtherTable] ON [MasterTable].[SomeOtherID]= [SomeOtherTable].[SomeOtherID]
```

I want to add an additional boolean column to this view the value of which will depend on the result of a condition on a subquery

```
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS (
     SELECT ErrorID
     FROM [ErrorTable]
          WHERE DetailID IN 
                (SELECT [DetailID]
                 FROM [DetailTable]
                      WHERE MasterID = [MasterTable].[MasterID])  
            )
THEN
     1
ELSE
     0
END
```

How do I something like this in my view? Also I am assuming that a nested query would exponentially degrade the performance as the number of rows go up. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I used the switch case AS 'ColumnName' to return the value from the view. I tried an alternative approach of using inner joins instead of the inner query too. However, the comparative performance seems to be better with the inner query but no so much. Could I improve this performance by any means?

Comment: doesn't SCHEMABINDING requiere [schema].[table]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing is that you don't need to assume that performance will get worse. SQL server can rewrite some subqueries to avoid the kind of row by row operation that I think you're assuming will happen. It's certainly possible that your subquery will slow down the view quite a bit but you can test this yourself. In fact, you can test this much more effectively than us because we have no idea about your table structures, indexes, statistics, size of the tables, etc.

Run queries that use the view with and without the bit column. Does the query with the new column get exponentially slower? Get an actual execution plan and analyze that. Run your queries after SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON and see how IO, CPU time, and elapsed time change with different queries.

I'll give you one way to rewrite that query without a subquery. I'm assuming that `[MasterID]` is unique for `[MasterTable]`.

Let's work through the logic of your subquery. One way to express it is you want to start with `[MasterTable].[MasterID]` and get all of the associated `[DetailID]` values from `[DetailTable]`. If there is at least one row in `[ErrorTable]` with a matching `DetailID` then the bit column has a value of 1. Otherwise it has a value of 0.

You can rewrite that to be a derived table. If the derived table has all of the distinct `[MasterID]` that have a corresponding entry in `[ErrorTable]` then you can do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to it. If the join column is not `NULL` then there was a match so your bit column has a value of 1. Otherwise it has a value of 0.

Here is one implementation:

```
SELECT
[MasterID],
[MasterColumnData],
[DetailID],
[DetailColumnData],
[SomeOtherID],
[SomeOtherColumnData],
CASE WHEN bool.[MasterID] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM [MasterTable]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [DetailTable] ON [MasterTable].[DetailID]= [DetailTable].[DetailID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [SomeOtherTable] ON [MasterTable].[SomeOtherID]= [SomeOtherTable].[SomeOtherID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT dt.[MasterID]
    FROM [DetailTable] dt
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [ErrorTable] et
        WHERE dt.DetailID = et.DetailID
    )
) bool ON [MasterTable].[MasterID] = bool.[MasterID];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `VIEW` works in `MS SQL Server 2016`, and is "as close as your original specification as possible" (I'm ignoring the `SCHEMABINDING`, as I don't think this is the core of the question):

```
CREATE VIEW [ForMasterTable] AS
SELECT
    [MasterID],
    [MasterColumnData],
    [MasterTable].[DetailID],
    [DetailColumnData],
    [MasterTable].[SomeOtherID],
    [SomeOtherColumnData],
    CAST (CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT ErrorID
          FROM [ErrorTable]
         WHERE DetailID IN 
                (SELECT [DetailID]
                   FROM [DetailTable]
                  WHERE MasterID = [MasterTable].[MasterID])  
        )
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS BIT) AS ErrorExists
FROM 
    [MasterTable]
    LEFT JOIN [DetailTable] ON [MasterTable].[DetailID]= [DetailTable].[DetailID]
    LEFT JOIN [SomeOtherTable] ON [MasterTable].[SomeOtherID]= [SomeOtherTable].[SomeOtherID] ;
```

I'm representing the boolean result as a 0=false/1=true bit (by just `CAST`ing).

Im curious at how does the execution plan look like with realistic data. It looks perfectly reasonable to me with (just a few rows of) simulated data, and I don't think it will worsen exponentially. It can degrade linearly, in the worst case. Most contemporry databases "understand" the EXISTS as a LEFT (SEMI-)JOIN, and the [DetaildID] IN as a JOIN, so, my guess is that SQL Server will generate a plan close to optimal.

---

The original tables are supposed to be similar to the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [DetailTable]
(
    DetailID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    DetailColumnData varchar
) ;

CREATE TABLE [SomeOtherTable]
(
    SomeOtherID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    SomeOtherColumnData varchar
) ;

CREATE TABLE [MasterTable]
(
    MasterID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    DetailID integer REFERENCES [DetailTable] (DetailID),
    SomeOtherID integer REFERENCES [SomeOtherTable] (SomeOtherID),
    MasterColumnData varchar
) ;

CREATE TABLE [ErrorTable]
(
    ErrorID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    DetailID integer REFERENCES DetailTable (DetailID)
) ;
```